# Vite/Rollup plugin: How to get styling (CSS module) into a React Web Component

Tags: reactjs, vite, web-component, rollup, css-modules

I am trying to create a Web Component from React. Web Components need you to import styles inside the Shadow DOM. So while my CSS module is imported like this normally

```
import css from "./MyComponent.css"

function MyComponent() {
  return <div className={css.container}>Hello</div>;
}
```

A Web component will need an extra step. With Vite, I can do the following

```
import css from "./MyComponent.css" // this is for the class names
import rawCss from "./MyComponent.css?inline" // this needs to be inside Shadow DOM

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <>
      <style>{rawCss}</style>
      <div className={css.container}>Hello</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

This works fine and dandy for simple components. However, for more complex components, I'll be importing other components that have their own CSS, etc. It would be tedious to need to do this every time.

I'm wondering if anyone had an idea on how to use Vite/Rollup to simplify the process. I'd like to have it read all the descendant files for CSS module files, and then compile them into a single raw CSS code string. **I'm stuck on figuring out how to get Rollup to give me a list of imported Ids of a target file**. Particularly, CSS module imports, so that I can read its contents.

The React Web Component would have a target area to add that code string.

```
unction MyComponent() {
  return (
    <>
      <style>{/* vite-plugin-webcomponent:CSSPlaceholder */}</style>
      <div className={css.container}>Hello</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update on 03/04/2024**

I have provided an answer to this question in the following related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78244034/5128443) that manages to solve this problem.

Additionally, if you want to extract the CSS into a separate bundle and inject it, you can follow these steps:

App.tsx:

```
function App() {
    // ... other code
    return (
        <>
            <style>{styles}</style>
            <div className="chrome-extension-boilerplate">
                {/* ...other components*/}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Main.tsx:

```
// Initialise container if it's not present
appContainer.id = contentScriptDom

// CSSURL must contain the path to your resource in remote,
// like "https://{urldomain}/css/bundle.css"
const shadowRoot = createShadowRoot(appContainer, cssURL) 

// Initialise React App
createRoot(shadowRoot).render(
    <StrictMode>
        <App />
    </StrictMode>,
)
```

Then, in your shadow DOM initialization, you can do as follows:

```
function attachStyleToShadowDom(shadowWrapper: ShadowRoot, cssContent: string) {
    // Create a variable to attach the tailwind stylesheet
    const style = document.createElement("style")

    // Attach the stylesheet as text
    style.textContent = cssContent

    // Apply the style
    shadowWrapper.appendChild(style)
}

export function createShadowRoot(root: Element, styles: string) {
    // Set shadow root inside of the root element
    const shadowRoot = root.attachShadow({ mode: "open" })
    root.appendChild(shadowRoot)
    
    // Add React App root node and styles
    const rootIntoShadow = document.createElement("div")
    rootIntoShadow.id = appRootId
    shadowRoot.appendChild(rootIntoShadow)
    
    // Attach styles to shadow DOM
    attachStyleToShadowDom(shadowRoot, styles)
    
    return rootIntoShadow
}
```

Then, in your `vite.config.ts` (or similar), you have to use:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import css from 'rollup-plugin-css-only'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react(), /* other plugins */, css({ output: "bundle.css" })],
    // other configurations
})
```

Make sure to replace placeholders like `{urldomain}` with your actual domain and configure paths and variables as needed for your project setup.

**Original answer on 03/03/2024**
This is a great question, and I find myself in a similar stage of development. While I don't have a complete solution yet, I'm exploring it from a technical perspective, and it seems to be an issue related to Vite configuration.

Though I lack a definitive answer, I have a theory I'd like to share with the community. Drawing from years of experience working with Webpack for Chrome Extension development, the challenge of CSS injection is often resolved using a plugin called "mini-css-extract-plugin." This plugin bundles all the CSS into a single file, and I believe a similar approach may be feasible within Vite.

Additionally, we utilize a library called "react-shadow" version 16.3.2 to inject styles into the shadow root of our components. I am currently exploring a package-less approach as I familiarize myself with Vite's bundling process and react-shadow implementation.

A potential solution might involve a combination of promises, leveraging the [fetch API](https://github.com/Wildhoney/ReactShadow/blob/v16.3.2/src/react-shadow.js#L256), to retrieve the necessary resources within the extension and successfully populate the styles.

Finally, I want to mention some of the links that inspired this answer: [extract CSS in a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75925404/5128443), [Assign a custom CSS file name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69327733/5128443), for extracting the CSS and storing it in a single place. However, please comment on this if you find a better approach.